# Draw for golf - social golfer

Tags: algorithm

How do you calculate a draw for say 16 people to play in groups of 4  over 4 days to achieve a result that they play with different people each day.

Comment: You should clarify the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's called the social golfer problem
I've found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20050217174950/http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sello/golf.html) to be useful.

Also this [demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem/)
and this [link](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html) from it,
both contain many interesting links at their bottom.

Comment: The answer for this particular problem is here: http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sello/solutions.html#5-4-4 
Looks like you can play for 5 days with 4 groups of 4.

Comment: The ~sello links are broken.

Comment: Thanks, Fixed and added new ones :).

Answer (score -2):

i remember from algo class that a network flow problem is what you are looking for